# Run Kotlin app from kotlin multiplatform documentation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, multiplatform

I downloaded a Kotlin app following the [Kotlin Multiplatform documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/kotlin-multiplatform-dev/compose-multiplatform-create-first-app.html#run-your-application).

However, I'm facing difficulty running it on the Android Studio emulator. Can anyone help me?

I've tried everything, but I can't find the "composeApp" mentioned in the documentation to select before running the code. As a result, the button to run the code isn't even available.

Comment: Have you make a successful Sync? by click "Sync Project with gradle Files"